# Cannot SSH ubuntu server

Tags: server, ssh

I cannot ssh to my server.  When I try ssh localhost on the server I get a "connection refused" message.  When I try remotely, I get Operation timed out message.

[image: screen dump of my server running]

Answer (score 2):

According to the screenshot you are trying to connect to a port **22** however your server is configured to listen to port **22222**.
Just type `ssh localhost -p 22222`. Should work.

Comment: I've gone into the config file and changed the setting to 22.   Now when I type "ssh localhost" I get a welcome message and then a Failed to connect to http://changlelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release.  Check your Internet connection or proxy settings.  I was trying to add a screen dump to this message but can't do so.

Comment: And I still can't ssh remotely.  I just get operation timed out.

Comment: How do you connect remotely to your server - using Putty for Windows or ssh command for Linux/MacOS? Also try to connect using IP address not DNS-name if you done so before.

Comment: I am trying to connect remotely via SSH in terminal for MAC.  I have tried both the IP address and the DNS-name to no avail.